# SQL getting a value based on id

Tags: sql

```
ID      DEPT
-------------
123       1
431       1
527       2
527       1
431       2
527       3
527       4
```

Given this table I'm struggling to find a way to return the ID that pairs with all values of DEPT as
desired result being
ID = 527

Comment: Looks like homework or exercise. What did you try? Post you SQL code and the result, even when undesired. Or describe your thought and steps planned! This helps us, see: [mcve]

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server or PostgresSQL?

Comment: I removed those conflicting dbms tags. The accepted answer is ANSI SQL compliant anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group by id` and count every id's distinct `dept`s.
This number must be the same as the number of distinct `dept`s of the table:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(distinct dept) = (select count(distinct dept) from tablename)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jSP7GS9GfJnhY7K1Bm7afQ/0).
Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 527 |
```

Comment: I was missing the having clause. Still new to sql. Thank you!